# Angular 1.3.15 front end on asp.net MVC 3 backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

We have an existing asp.net mvc 3 applicaiton.
We want to reskin it with angular 1.3.15.

I'm looking for a tutorial or example that takes a asp.net mvc 3 application and using the correct 1.3.15 syntax shows how to set up all the angular front end talking to the .Net backend.

I can find lots of angular 1.2 examples, but they dont' work under .1.3.15.. routing is different, 1.2 style submit doest't work.. I'm wasintg all my time trying to find out esoteric differenteces betwee 1.2 and 1.3, when I'm trying to learn the very basics of an angular mini spa app on top of ask.net mvc with best practices.

Can you pleae point me towards tutoprial or code samples that teach best practices with 1.3.5 syntax on the front end, binding routing etc..to asp.net mvc on the back end (3,4 or 5)

There are so many 1.2 examples and tutorials, that I can't find the wheat for the chaff...

Comment: 1.3 is actually mostly backwards compatible with 1.2 so you shouldn't see a large difference there.  Regarding using .net mvc most of the tutorials assume that you have some server side API that uses JSON for the requests and responses but aside from that the angular side could be served up from a static file server.  Regarding the routing would suggest you just use ui-router at least for the time being until the switch to 1.4 or 2.0 with the new angular router.  If you have a specific problem search for it the breaking changes https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks! What I'm reading on the web seems to indicate that changing the conroller level over to web api is proabably the way to go, does that match with your experience?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean exactly by the "controller level" (not intimately familiar with .NET MVC).  The easiest way I can say to explain it is if you can make an API where you make HTTP requests with JSON encoded data in the request body and response body then you can integrate that with an angular front-end pretty easily.  In terms of what part of the backend you'll need I typically just write things in PHP on the server side and use Eloquent for ORM to fetch objects from a DB and Slim to setup routes (some custom code for converting the PHP objects -> JSON and back, and for REST/CRUD).